# How to bind to 2 elements in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

How can I bind the `Visibility` of the `Grid` element to two `Checkbox` elements. I want the grid to be displayed if at least one of them is checked. ***I do not want to use converters.***

Here is what I have:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Identifies whether the tags will be copied from source to target host
  /// </summary>
  private bool pasteTags = true;
  public bool PasteTags
  {
     get { return pasteTags; }
     set
     {
        pasteTags = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("PasteTags");
     }
  }


  /// <summary>
  /// Identifies whether the dimensions will be copied from source to target host
  /// </summary>
  private bool pasteDimensions = true;
  public bool PasteDimensions
  {
     get { return pasteDimensions; }
     set
     {
        pasteDimensions = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("PasteDimensions");
     }
  }


  /// <summary>
  /// Identifies if the views data grid is displayed or not.
  /// </summary>      
  public System.Windows.Visibility IsViewGridVisible
  {
     get
     {
        if (pasteDimensions || pasteTags)
           return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
     }
  }
```

**XAML:**

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding IsViewGridVisible}"> </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that you need is call to `RaisePropertyChanged("IsViewGridVisible");` in both setters of properties `PasteDimensions` and `PasteTags`.

```
public bool PasteDimensions
  {
     get { return pasteDimensions; }
     set
     {
        pasteDimensions = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("PasteDimensions");
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsViewGridVisible");
     }
  }
```

This is required because you `IsViewGridVisible` depends on both values of those properties and WPF needs to be informed about the change (it cannot figure it out any other way).

Comment: But then it will still raise if both are unchecked!

Comment: @Vahid yes and you want that to hide your grid. If both are unchecked they your `IsViewGridVisible` will retrun `Collapsed` - it did change.

Comment: Thanks. I got it now!

Answer (score 1):

You do not actually need the `IsViewGridVisible` property.

Instead, you could define a Style that sets the Grid's `Visibility` by a `MultiDataTrigger` on the `PasteTags` and `PasteDimensions` properties:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding PasteTags}" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding PasteDimensions}" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The difference is that it implements the logic in the view, while the other approach implements the logic in the view model. It's a software design decision.

Comment: If this is a purely view-related aspect, you might even drop the PasteTags and PasteDimensions properties from your view model, and bind directly to the IsChecked properties of the two CheckBoxes.